# Automapper - Does it map lists of objects?

Tags: automapper

I have the following Automapper defintion:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IB.BusinessComponents.Data.LocationMaster, IB.Entites.Master.Location>();
Mapper.CreateMap<IB.BusinessComponents.Data.LocationMaster, IB.Entites.Master.Location>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Id, source => source.MapFrom(item => item.LocationMasterID))
    .ForMember(destination => destination.ChildLocationList, source => source.Ignore());
```

This works fine when I map a single object.  But I can't seem to pass in Lists of objects. Do I need a different definition when passing in a list, or is it not possible?

Comment: Why do you have the same mapping twice? You should only define it once (presumably the second one)

Comment: @BeRecursive - Probably because I have a grand total of 2 hours experience with this tool.

Comment: Well i should work with lists out of the box as long as you define the mapping correctly. Do you mean lists of the above type? You don't need to define mappings for lists of explicit objects, just define the mappings for the type of object you want to map and lists should 'just work'

Answer (score 157, accepted):

In your AutoMapper Definition:

```
    CreateMap<MyStuffDTO, MyStuffViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.MyDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastDate))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.MyTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastTime))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Category, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category));
```

In code:

For Single:

```
var result = Mapper.Map<MyStuffDTO, MyStuffViewModel>(obj);
```

For List:

```
var list = Mapper.Map<IList<MyStuffDTO>, IList<MyStuffViewModel>>(obj);
```

Comment: [AutoMap(typeof(List<Category>), typeof(List<CategoryViewModel>))] can I use it like this in MVC ???

Comment: this is outdated, Mapper is no more a static class. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807216/automapper-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-prop for an updated solution