# How to Manually mapa viewmodel with lists to dto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to backend development, having some trouble mapping a viewmodel to dto that has a list.

Can you help me figure out whats wrong with the mapper. The result is coming in correct from the dto. I have a list of 7 items. When it maps to the view they are gone.

Here is the viewmodel

```
public class StatisticsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ProviderId { get; set; }
    public List<StatisticsTotalsViewModel> Totals { get; set; } = new List<StatisticsTotalsViewModel>();
    public List<StatisticsProvidersViewModel> Providers { get; set; } = new List<StatisticsProvidersViewModel>();
}

public class StatisticsTotalsViewModel
{
    public string PayerName { get; set; }
    public string PayerType { get; set; }
    public short Status { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalBalance { get; set; }
}
```

Heres the dto

```
public class StatisticsDto
{
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ProviderId { get; set; }
    public List<StatisticsTotalsDto> Totals { get; set; } = new List<StatisticsTotalsDto>();
    public List<StatisticsProvidersDto> Providers { get; set; } = new List<StatisticsProvidersDto>();
}

public class StatisticsTotalsDto
{
    public string PayerName { get; set; }
    public string PayerType { get; set; }
    public short Status { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalBalance { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the mapper

```
    public static StatisticsViewModel MapToView(StatisticsDto dto)
    {
        var viewmodel = new StatisticsViewModel();

        viewmodel.StartDate = dto.StartDate;
        viewmodel.EndDate = dto.EndDate;
        viewmodel.ProviderId = dto.ProviderId;

        var dtoTotals = new List<StatisticsTotalsDto>();
        var totals = new List<StatisticsTotalsViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in dtoTotals)
        {
            var totalsModel = new StatisticsTotalsViewModel();
            item.PayerName = totalsModel.PayerName;
            item.PayerType = totalsModel.PayerType;
            item.Status = totalsModel.Status;
            item.TotalBalance = totalsModel.TotalBalance;
            item.TotalCount = totalsModel.TotalCount;
            totals.Add(totalsModel);
        }

        viewmodel.Totals = totals;

       return viewmodel;

    }
```

Comment: What is `PayerClaimStatisticsViewModel`? And your just looping through `dtoTotals` which you initialize as an empty collection. And your method returns `StatisticsViewModel` but contains no `return` statement

Comment: Thank you! One was a typo but you got me pointed in the right direction

Comment: The I assume what you want is `foreach (var item in dto.Totals)`

Comment: You should also check out Automapper. It's pretty much the accepted standard for mapping like this.

Comment: I checked out AutoMapper but couldn't find much help with the new version. As Im still learning I need some good examples and couldnt find them

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this line. Instead

```
var dtoTotals = new List<StatisticsTotalsDto>();
```

You need to receive list of StatisticsTotalsDto, instead of create new empty list

```
var dtoTotals = dto.Totals;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `Automapper.`

Say for example:

```
public static StatisticsViewModel MapToView(StatisticsDto dto)
{
     Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<StatisticsDto, StatisticsViewModel>());
     var ViewModel = Mapper.Map<StatisticsViewModel>(dto);

     return viewModel;
}
```

Take a look at [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) to know more about `Automapper`. You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589471/mapping-lists-using-automapper) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276664/automapper-does-it-map-lists-of-objects) if you face problem mapping list items.

**P.S** Don't forget to include `Automapper` to your project and add `using Automapper()` at the top where you are using it