# Automapper Object reference is required for the non static field, method or property

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, automapper-9

I recently Upgraded my .net core to 3.0 and Automapper from 6.2 to 9.0. Now the automapper is throwing the following compile time error when using mapper.map inside mapfrom function.

```
CreateMap<DomainEntity, destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.userId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<.UserInfo, string>(src.UserDetails)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.alertKey, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Key));
```

**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Mapper.Map(xxx)'**

Automapper has removed static keyword in its new upgrade for Mapper class Methods.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Comment: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/

Comment: Yes, but that's outdated. http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 18):

Your question was specific to profile of the mapper but the post title ties with the below issue too. In my case, it was not exact same problem but I was getting same error. So I wanted to share this for anyone who had same error like mine.

Looks like Automapper is not a static class anymore. So you will need to instantiate it. To be able to do that, you will need to install the package :

`Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

Once it is done, than you can inject IMapper instance in your class like:

```
public MyClass {

     private readonly IMapper _mapper;

     public MyClass(IMapper mapper){
          _mapper = mapper;
     }

     public DtoType SomeMethod(EntityType entity){
          // do your mapping..
          var myDtoType = _mapper.Map<DtoType>(entity);
     }
}
```

Important part is, it **may look like a bit of black magic since you never registered IMapper in the ServiceCollection**. But the Nuget package and the call to “AddAutoMapper” in your ConfigureServices takes care of all of this for you.

PS: didn't write the code on VS but you got the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I also encounter the problem recently, here is what I did

Installed this package `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`. This package is a dependency on AutoMapper. It also contains ASP.NET core specific extensions for AutoMapper allowing it to play nice with the built-in dependency injection system.

Then follow the steps on the link below. Then you should be good to go

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/